# Saving content from JTextArea into file with line separators

Tags: java, lines, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I have a problem with writing to file.

Generally I am creating simple text editor. I load file in this way:

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(currentlyEditedFile))) {
            String line = "";
            editor.setText("");
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                editor.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and the after some modifications, I want to save(write) it back to the file.

I am doing it in this way:

```
try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(currentlyEditedFile)))) {
            String[] lines = editor.getText().split("\\n");//Tried \n, \\n
            for(String s : lines)
                pw.println(s);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and the content goes to the file, but it is all in one line. Any ideas how to write line by line?

Comment: Are you using windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may load content of a text file into `JTextArea` in following simple way:

```
 JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
 FileReader reader = new FileReader("D:/text1.txt");
 textArea.read(reader, "Content of File");
 reader.close();
```

You may write content of `JTextArea` to a file in following simple and platform independent way:

```
 PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter("D:/text1.txt");
 textArea.write(pw);
 pw.close();
```

Hope, this is helpful to you.

Comment: Nice simple way, but it has the same effects so as my solution. Loading content into JTextArea works properly, but saving puts content in one line. :)

Comment: @DamDev Please look at the original file. Does it have everything on single line?  If you use `\r\n`  will it work the same way on linux? I have actually tested it on my Windows system,  it seems to work fine.

Comment: Yea, my bad. Just loaded file generated by pravious method, probably that's why it didn't work. I have tried it once again and it works fine. Thank you! :)

Comment: @DamDev Please create a text file using a text editor like` Notepad++`  and run my solution. Please tell me what you see.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, then you should do:

```
editor.append(line + "\r\n");
```

Because the new-line in Windows is denoted by `\r\n`, i.e., a carriage-return and a line-feed.